# Cannot resize my disk space in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gparted, disk, 23.10, resize

I have recently moved to a new system and installed Ubuntu 23.10 as dual boot with Windows. I have copied all my files which were around 15GB and set up all the applications and software that were present in the old one. After some days I noticed that I had only allocated around 34GB of storage space for my filesystem when I got a "Low storage" notification in my system.

So I looked for the solution on the internet and found some solutions that are performed in the Ubuntu installed in the VMs. I used Gparted to resize my filesystem storage space but faced an error below:

[image: error-on-resize-option]

I tried to check the same on the internet but found no solution. What should I do to increase my storage? Here is the Gparted disk space and partition image:

[image: gparted]

Comment: You can't extend a partition to the left. Either backup-wipe-reinstall or since the unallocated is bigger than the partition, install-copy-delete-extend. Moving the partition could work but is unnecessarily slow and risky

Comment: @DanielT, so you are asking me to install the Ubuntu in the unallocated partition, copy the contents from the existing one to the new one, delete the existing and extend that partition to the new one??

Comment: That's the second option I mentioned, yes

Comment: You cannot modify mounted partitions. Little lock icons in gparted show partition is mounted. Use live installer. You have to move partition left & expand right. Be sure to have good backups as any interruption leaves data partially copied & then it is corrupted. depending on amount of data it can take a long time to move. Then expand right will be quick.

Comment: @DanielT, your second solution is working well for me. I didn't know the issues with merging partitions to the left. Thanks a lot for the solution. You can add that as your answer if you want.